# Bootstrap: Input text border turning black before applying CSS-applied grey?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a visualization of my problem: 
[image]

I used CSS to make the borders light grey, yet for a millisecond they default to a black border before turning light grey. I would really appreciated if someone could give me a tip on this!

**HTML file**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row page-header">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Worksheet Name..." aria-label="Write worksheet name here">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" id="Remove-Button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Remove">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" id="Add-Button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Add">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS borders part**

```
/*Take away default black borders*/
input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: none;
}

/*Put grey borders when hover or click on input box*/
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap and running my HTML file on Chrome if that's relevant.

[JSFiddle of my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/k1pjs79c/)

Comment: Are you loading your css at the top of the page?

Comment: @user3791775 yeah I connect the CSS in `<head>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change:

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

To:

```
input[type="text"]  {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Your gray outline remains, the color glitch is removed, but on focus your outline does change blue.

Comment: @15ongm Try setting the border color in your default state to white of transparent, and then applying the `:focus, :hover` styles after.  At the very least that should alleviate the odd shifting you get when you go from no border to border when you hover.

Answer (score 1):

just add    `transition:none;`

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
    input[type="text"]:hover {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-radius: 8px;
      transition:none;
    }
```